# Check PDF file version from command line

Tags: pdf, file-format

Is there any command line tool available on Linux to check a PDF file version?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  The `file` command covers this

```
$ file x1.pdf
x1.pdf: PDF document, version 1.7
$
```

To get greater detail, you could try `pdfinfo`, part of popper-utils.

```
$ pdfinfo x1.pdf
Title:          Full page photo
Author:         steve
Producer:       Microsoft: Print To PDF
CreationDate:   Fri Apr  5 10:14:34 2019
ModDate:        Fri Apr  5 10:14:34 2019
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          9
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      841.5 x 594.75 pts
Page rot:       0
File size:      5424973 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.7
$
```

Comment: How do you find out, if your file is in the Format `PDF/X-1a:2001`?

Answer (score 1):

With `exiftool`:

```
$ exiftool -T -PDFVersion test.pdf
1.5
```

More generally, `exiftool` can extra metadata from hundreds of different file formats. To know which flag to use for the particular metadata you're interested in, you can use `-args`:

```
$ exiftool -args test.pdf
-ExifToolVersion=12.44
-FileName=test.pdf
-Directory=.
-FileSize=28 kB
-FileModifyDate=2011:10:04 09:30:28+01:00
-FileAccessDate=2022:08:24 10:39:03+01:00
-FileInodeChangeDate=2018:01:16 15:54:47+00:00
-FilePermissions=-rw-------
-FileType=PDF
-FileTypeExtension=pdf
-MIMEType=application/pdf
-PDFVersion=1.5
-Linearized=No
-PageCount=1
-Creator=cairo 1.10.2 (http://cairographics.org)
-Producer=cairo 1.10.2 (http://cairographics.org)
```

Or the JSON (`-j`), CSV (`-csv`), PHP (`-php`) or XML (`-X`) formats which all show the tag names (as opposed to textual description) for each metadata.

Comment: Be careful when using exiftool, the output may be wrong (see comment below)

Comment: `root@box:/tmp# pdfinfo /tmp/bc08cf138f076d47bb783e7162ddc969555e320153be25336942ed7ae706762b.pdf | grep version
` output: `PDF version:    1.4`

Comment: `root@box:/tmp# file /tmp/bc08cf138f076d47bb783e7162ddc969555e320153be25336942ed7ae706762b.pdf ` output: `/tmp/bc08cf138f076d47bb783e7162ddc969555e320153be25336942ed7ae706762b.pdf: PDF document, version 1.4`

Comment: `root@box:/tmp# exiftool -T -PDFVersion /tmp/bc08cf138f076d47bb783e7162ddc969555e320153be25336942ed7ae706762b.pdf ` output: `1.7`

Comment: As shown in my command output above, using `file` and `poppler-utils`'s `pdfinfo` returns pdf version 1.4 (correct), while using `exiftool` was showing 1.7 (wrong)

Comment: @Kristian I can't reproduce with any of the 300+ PDFs on my system. What's the output of `grep -Poa '%PDF-[\d.]+' your-file.pdf`?

Comment: it's `%PDF-1.4`

Comment: also, here's the base64 of the pdf's first 5 line: `head bc08cf138f076d47bb783e7162ddc969555e320153be25336942ed7ae706762b.pdf | base64 -w0`, outputs: `JVBERi0xLjQNCiXi48/TDQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KL1R5cGUgL1BhZ2UNCi9NZWRpYUJveCBbIDAgMCA1OTQuOTYgODQyLjA0IF0NCi9SZXNvdXJjZXMgPDwgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZSA8PCAvR1M2IDMgMCBSIC9HUzkgNCAwIFIgPj4gL1hPYmplY3QgPDwgL0ltYWdlNQ0KNSAwIFIgPj4gL0ZvbnQgPDwgL0YxIDYgMCBSIC9GMiA3IDAgUiAvRjMgOCAwIFIgPj4gPj4NCi9Db250ZW50cyA5IDAgUg0KL0dyb3VwIDw8IC9UeXBlIC9Hcm91cCAvUyAvVHJhbnNwYXJlbmN5IC9DUyAvRGV2aWNlUkdCID4+DQo=`

Comment: you can decode it and see the first 5 line of the pdf with command: `echo 'JVBERi0xLjQNCiXi48/TDQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KL1R5cGUgL1BhZ2UNCi9NZWRpYUJveCBbIDAgMCA1OTQuOTYgODQyLjA0IF0NCi9SZXNvdXJjZXMgPDwgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZSA8PCAvR1M2IDMgMCBSIC9HUzkgNCAwIFIgPj4gL1hPYmplY3QgPDwgL0ltYWdlNQ0KNSAwIFIgPj4gL0ZvbnQgPDwgL0YxIDYgMCBSIC9GMiA3IDAgUiAvRjMgOCAwIFIgPj4gPj4NCi9Db250ZW50cyA5IDAgUg0KL0dyb3VwIDw8IC9UeXBlIC9Hcm91cCAvUyAvVHJhbnNwYXJlbmN5IC9DUyAvRGV2aWNlUkdCID4+DQo=' | base64 -d`

Comment: also, here's the base64 of the pdf's last 5 line: tail bc08cf138f076d47bb783e7162ddc969555e320153be25336942ed7ae706762b.pdf | base64 -w0, outputs: `MDAwMDMxMzQ0MyAwMDAwMCBuDQp0cmFpbGVyDQo8PA0KL1NpemUgMjg5DQovUm9vdCAyODggMCBSDQovSUQgWzw1ZDQxZjRmMTBkOGNhMThhYzJiMGQ4ODRmY2YzMWNmZj48NWQ0MWY0ZjEwZDhjYTE4YWMyYjBkODg0ZmNmMzFjZmY+XQ0KPj4NCnN0YXJ0eHJlZg0KMzEzNjAyDQolJUVPRg0K`

Comment: you can decode it and see the last 5 line of the pdf with command: `echo 'MDAwMDMxMzQ0MyAwMDAwMCBuDQp0cmFpbGVyDQo8PA0KL1NpemUgMjg5DQovUm9vdCAyODggMCBSDQovSUQgWzw1ZDQxZjRmMTBkOGNhMThhYzJiMGQ4ODRmY2YzMWNmZj48NWQ0MWY0ZjEwZDhjYTE4YWMyYjBkODg0ZmNmMzFjZmY+XQ0KPj4NCnN0YXJ0eHJlZg0KMzEzNjAyDQolJUVPRg0K' | base64 -d`